# Impedir collapse do Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou utilizando o Bootstrap em meu site e estou fazendo uma barra com o navbar.

O menu consiste em um brand, 3 itens "li", uma barra de busca e um link.

Como eu poderia fazer para que ao utilizar em telas menores ou mesmo ao redimensionar o navegador, a barra de busca não entraria nesse "collapse"?

Código atual:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Minha Empresa</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      
        <input type="text" id="OmniSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar..." />
       
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Entrar / Cadastro</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Menu completo atual:
[image: Menu completo atualmete]

Menu reduzido:

[image: Menu reduzido]

Minha dúvida é como fazer para que a barra de busca permaneça visível no modo "collapsed"?

Existe alguma classe anti-collapse no Bootstrap?

Obrigado.

Comment: Voce deseja colocar ela do lado do Minha Empresa  quando estiver no collapse ?

Comment: algo assim ? https://jsfiddle.net/filadown/uus86wxb/

Comment: Talvez seja mais prático fazer 2 menus: um para desktop e outro para mobile. Então use regras `@media` para escondê-los de acordo com o tamanho da tela.

Comment: Isso mesmo @GabrielRodrigues, muito obrigado. Irei estudar esse código e irei implementar lá. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @JuniorZancan já que é isto que você precisa adicionei o comentário como resposta para que outras pessoas possam conhecer a possível solução

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apenas adicionei o `search` dentro do `navbar-header` e ficou um pouco desalinhado o search do brand, então adicionei `@media` para reconfigurar o navbar em mobile.

### Exemplo:

```css
@media(max-width:767px) {
  .navbar .navbar-form {
    width: 185px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
  .navbar .navbar-form {
    width: 250px;
  }
}
.navbar .navbar-form {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand hidden-xs" href="#" title="Desktop">Minha Empresa</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs" href="#" title="Mobile">Minha Empresa</a>
      <form class="navbar-form pull-left" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">Item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Item 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navbar-link">Entrar / Cadastro</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Veja funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/uus86wxb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente eu usaria JavaScript para fazer o collapse:

```
$('.collapse').collapse()
```

Dentro de uma condicional, para verificar o tamanho da tela:

```
if (window.screen.width < 480) { // collapse }
```

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade você está utilizando classes e atributos que incentivam o collapse do menu, como por exemplo: data-toggle="collapse", class="navbar-toggle collapsed". Tente remover esses trechos de código e teste novamente. Espero que isso ajude.

Comment: Mas isso seria o caso se eu quisesse impedir todo o collapse, eu preciso impedir apenas o collapse da barra de busca.

Comment: Certo, você poderia criar 2 menus e utilizar as classes utilitárias do bootstrap para gerenciar a versão web e mobile http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities